# AngularJS ng-class applying class based on boolean

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to apply style to div element based on boolean value. What am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<div ng-class="{'checkedClass': vm.siteLoadedSuccess, 'uncheckedClass': !vm.siteLoadedSuccess}">
```

css:

```
  .uncheckedClass {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .checkedClass {
       margin-left:220px;
    }
```

Comment: Looks fine. Are you sure `vm.siteLoadedSuccess` exists in the scope? Can we see the controller code and the rest of the template code?

Comment: @neela information is lacking please post your controller code too thank you.